# Dynamic URL respective to Tcode

Tags: url, sap-gui, sap-bsp

I want to create URL dynamically when I give Tcode. Is there any function module or Class to export URL when we import Tcodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WEBGUI is the service for SAP GUI for HTML. When we execute that service, then the URL will be

**http://hostname:portno/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui**

We have to concatenate **~transaction=tcode** . Then that URL can be used to open Tcode in SAP GUI for HTML.